# How do I recover my Base URLs on the internet not phpMyAdmin?

Tags: database, installation, base-url

I changed Base Urls by Open the Unsecure and Secure dropdowns, locate the base URL line, and replace this with the new URL. But now my website is inaccessible

How do I change or restore base_url my BaseURL settings back?

I just changed it by the link login , and i dont have any systems

Answer (score 0):

Without any access to the database this is going to be tough. You really should try to get access or let somebody who has access change the base URLs.

As a last resort, you can make a backup copy of `app/etc/local.xml`, then delete the file. Now, when you open the site, you will be greeted with the Magento installation wizard. During setup it will ask you for the base URL.

For database credentials and cryptographic key, enter the values that you find in your backup copy of `local.xml`

Comment: thanks , as i cant access phpMyAdmin by myself. it ' s on other computer